# What happens if I create a folder without it's parents?

Tags: filesystems

I have seen in some documentation about various software that this is apparently possible.

However, I don't understand what exactly happens then. Is it just the parents not being accessible, or is the folder then lost in the mist of a corrupted file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very curious to see this documentation, because a directory cannot exist without its entry being contained in its parent.

Technically it is possible to "create a folder without creating its parents", but generally this involves creating the parent directories *implicitly*, e.g. via `mkdir -p`.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is a bit confusingly phrased, because `mkdir -p` _doesn't_ "technically" create a folder without creating its parents, it does the exact opposite...